# Django FileField/ImageField validation when the file upload is being done from the client side

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

When ever client wants to upload a file it first request the Django server for a `pre-signed` URL the server then generates a `pre-signed` URL and sends it back to the client.

The client can use this URL to upload to file directly to S3. Once the upload is successful the client sends the file key back to the server (the file key is also present in the response given by the server along with the URL).

Now I'm confused as to how to pass the FileField validation given that I only have the file key with me and not the actual file. For example:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.ImageField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'name:{self.name}'


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    CLIENT_COMPANY_LOGO_KEY = 'logo'

    def to_internal_value(self, data):

        # Replace file/image keys with file/image instances so that they can pass validation.
        if data.get(self.CLIENT_COMPANY_LOGO_KEY):
            try:
                data[self.CLIENT_COMPANY_LOGO_KEY] = default_storage.open(data[self.CLIENT_COMPANY_LOGO_KEY])
            except (TypeError, OSError, ParamValidationError):
                pass

        return super().to_internal_value(data)

    def process_logo(self, validated_data):
        logo = validated_data.get(self.CLIENT_COMPANY_LOGO_KEY)
        if logo:
            # Replace file/image instances with keys.
            validated_data[self.CLIENT_COMPANY_LOGO_KEY] = logo.name

        return validated_data

    def create(self, validated_data):

        validated_data = self.process_logo(validated_data)

        company = super().create(validated_data)

        return company
```

Within the serializer I'm first replacing the file key with the actual file using the `default_storage` which is hooked up to S3 using `django-storages`. Then once the file has been successfully validated, I then again replace the actual file with the file key in the `process_logo` function.

The reason I replace the actual file with the file is because it is slowing down the `create` method (upto 30s).

I feel like this is a very hacky method and wanted to know if there is a better way to handle this situation. Should I replace the `FileField`/`ImageField` with a `CharField` and not do any validation?

Or maybe use celery to do the validation? But then what if the validation fails? How should the server inform the client that the validation has failed for some reason in the background?

Comment: You're returning a URL that allows a client to upload an arbitrary file to your S3 bucket?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes that is correct. You can read more about it here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html